# terraform jsoncode secret manager

Tags: postgresql, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-secrets-manager

I have `secrets` on `AWS secret manager` and I have to retrieve these `secrets` on `terraform`.
I am using `data` to retrieve the `secrets` and I receive `JSON` with all the `secrets` configured on `AWS secret manager`:

```
data "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "secrets_manager_rds" {
  secret_id = "rds-sm"
}
```

in order to parse this `JSON`, I am using `jsondecode` on `locals`:

```
locals {
rds = jsondecode(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.secrets_manager_rds.secret_string)
}
```

Now I can get the secrets by specifying the `secret key` (password_rds) in the `rds-sm` secret:

```
local.rds.password_rds
```

I want the ability to loop through the `JSON` without specifying a specific `secret key`, for example, to use `for_each` with `jsoncode` output.

I need to loop through a resource with `for_each`. for example:

```
resource "postgresql_role" "test" {
  for_each = [for k in local.rds : k]
  name     = each.key
  password = each.value
  login    = true
  skip_reassign_owned = true
  roles = ["readonlyrole"]
}
```

I receive:

```
local.users_creds has a sensitive value 
Sensitive values, or values derived from sensitive values, cannot be used as for_each arguments. If used, the sensitive
value could be exposed as a resource instance key.
```

Is it possible?

Comment: How does you secret string look like?

Comment: I receive json with all the secrets. for example:
`{"secret_string": {"secretname1": "secretvalue1","secretname2": "secretvalue2"}}`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your JSON string in the comments, you can do this:

```
locals {
  secrets = jsondecode(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.secrets_manager_rds.secret_string)
}

output "secrets" {
  value = [
    for secret_name, secret_value in local.secrets.secret_string:
     "${secret_name}: ${secret_value}"
  ]
}
```

Output:

```
Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

secrets = [
  "secretname1: secretvalue1",
  "secretname2: secretvalue2",
]
```

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory. It seems that Terraform won't allow you to use `sensitive` values in `for_each`, and apparently, it considers the output of a secrets data source to be sensitive. You can try using SSM parameters instead.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's a terraform security feature.
Is there a workaround for this? or an alternate way to accomplish this goal?

Comment: Try using the [nonsensitive](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/nonsensitive.html) function (`for secret_name, secret_value in nonsensitive(local.secrets.secret_string)`).